# First occurrence of each value in a vector depending on a condition

Tags: r

From a vector:

```
v <- c(2,2,2,2,5,7,7,5,5,7,3,3,3)
```

and according to the condition `v[i] != v[i+1]`, how can I obtain:

```
[1] 2 5 7 5 7 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `rle` function will do this. rle stands for run length encoding.

```
v <- c(2,2,2,2,5,7,7,5,5,7,3,3,3)
rle(v)$values
## [1] 2 5 7 5 7 3
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be also done using `diff`

```
v[c(TRUE,diff(v)!=0)]
#[1] 2 5 7 5 7 3
```

Or using `rleid` from `library(data.table)`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(list(v))[,V1[1L] ,rleid(V1)]$V1
#[1] 2 5 7 5 7 3
```